# Where to pass "Partner code"? I am getting following error

Tags: php

```
Error: call to URL https://cs31.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/CreateLoan/ failed with status 200, response HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 08:18:26 GMT Set-Cookie: BrowserId=My_9dHEtQwGKzujO5w73-w;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Sat, 30-Apr-2016 08:18:26 GMT Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked " message - Invalid Partner Code,", curl_error , curl_errno 0
```

And I am using following Code

```
{'access_token'};
create_account($name, $instance_url, $access_token);
function create_account($name, $instance_url, $access_token) {
    $url = $instance_url;
    //$content = json_encode(array("Name" => $name));

    $content='{"loanAppWrapper":
                {
                "location":"Mumbai",
                "lob":"PL",
                "createdBy":"Customer",
                "partnerName":"Company ABC",
                "firstName":"TestFirst",
                "lastName":"XYZ",
                "middleName":"XYZ",
                "loanSource":"PLOnline",
                "gender":"Male",
                "maritalStatus":"Single",
                "dateOfBirth":"11/12/1982",
                "mobileNumber":"9999999999",
                "emailId":"abc@sf.com",
                "PAN":"abcpk1241f",
                "voterId":"abc1234567",
                "passportNumber":"K1234567",
                "listAddress":
                [{"addressLine1":"addressLine1",
                "addressLine2":"addressLine2",
                "pincode":"400001",
                "addressType":"RESIDENCE ADDRESS",
                "landmark":"Near XYZ Store"}]
                }

                }';
    //echo $content;
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token",
                "Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    //echo $json_response;
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $status != 201 ) {
        die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
    }

    echo "HTTP status $status creating account

";

    curl_close($curl);

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    echo $response;
    $id = $response["id"];

    echo "New record id $id

";

    return $id;
}
?>
```

Comment: seems u r calling a custom apex rest api from salesforce which is expecting partnerCode in the request.. in the $content you are passing in, I can see you are setting partnerName already.. if you have the Code for the partner, set it to partnerCode next to it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no issue with your(PHP) code.

To confirm that there is not issue with your code I have refereed cookbook recipe. http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php

So, I leads me to think that this error is returned by Rest API.

There is easy way to verify above understanding.

login to https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php and got to utilities -> Rest Explorer

Then enter your api URL as https://cs31.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/CreateLoan

And enter your json data click subumit. If you get same error its probably issue with Rest API(or may be data validation in api )

Comment: Thanks @Vamsi Krishna and AtulRajguru. It resolves my error and I am getting application number now. I just want to ask, I am getting this application mumbar with this error"Error: call to URL https://cs31.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/CreateLoan/ failed with status 200, response HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 08:30:01 GMT Set-Cookie: BrowserId=1XBCUON2SLyQSlrJCmI_7g;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Sat, 30-Apr-2016 08:30:01 GMT Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked "success: Loan Application Number - 8043